# Check if function output exists in list then add to another list

Tags: python

So basically I have this simple function that adds the sum to the empty `myUnique` list.

I want to check if the output `sum` exists in the empty list, if not add to another empty list, else add to the unique list.

```py
myUniqueList = []

def add_Item_To_List(item):
    sum = item + 36
    return sum

var = 37
var2 = add_Item_To_List(var)
myUniqueList.append(var2)
var3 = add_Item_To_List(var2)
myUniqueList.append(var3)
var4 = add_Item_To_List(var3)
myUniqueList.append(var4)

print(myUniqueList)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. You haven't checked the list to decide whether output exists. In order to check whether `x` exists in list, you can do `if x in myUniqueList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you wanted two lists; empty and myunique. Is this what you want?

```
myUniqueList = []
emptyList = []
ITERATION = 3
def add_Item_To_List(item):
    sum = item + 36
    return sum

var = 37
for i in range(0, ITERATION):
    var = add_Item_To_List(var)
    if var in emptyList:
        myUniqueList.append(var)
    else:
        emptyList.append(var)

print(myUniqueList)
print(emptyList)
```